# Problem with creation of executable file with cx_freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze

If I try to build the executable and I get the following error message:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'C:\OSGEO5\apps\Python27\dlls\sqlite3.dll.

This file is located in the same folder on my machine the only different is it is called `_sqlite3.dll`.

I changed the file name and removed the `_` with the same result. I searched the web for the error with no helpful results. I tried it out with a different py file and it worked. The different between the two py files is one uses GDAL NumPy and is working the other one is not using those libraries and is working.

My setup file looks like this:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable

setup(
    name='wind_of_change',
    version='0.2', 
    description='ooo',
    executables = [Executable('sen2cor_if_state.py')]
)
```

I expect an executable like I have produced before. At the moment the exe is just closing when ran.

Comment: I'd suggest trying PyInstaller instead of cx_freeze.

Comment: I did with no satisfactory result.